# How can I draw an image on to a rounded rectangle? (Java)

Tags: java, graphics

How can I draw a buffered Image onto a rounded rectangle? I overwrote a paintComponent method, but the call `graphics.setClip(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1, getArcRadius(),getArcRadius()));` does NOT work, because a rounded rectangle is not a rectangle and the setClip method only works on rectangles.

The code so far:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    if (g instanceof Graphics2D) {
        //Render smooth
        Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

        if(image == null) {
            //Draw alternative color
            graphics.setColor(alternative);
            graphics.fillRoundRect(0, 0, getWidth()-1, getHeight()-1, getArcRadius(),
                    getArcRadius());
        } else {
            //Draw image
            graphics.setClip(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1, getArcRadius(),
                    getArcRadius()));

            graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        }
    }
}
```

alternative is just some kind of color (can be null which is black) and is only drawn when the image can not be found / is null. Please only regard the `else` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use clip() not setClip(). The newer clip() method accepts an arbitrary shape.

```
        graphics.clip(new RoundRectangle2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth()-1,getHeight()-1, getArcRadius(),
                getArcRadius()));
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much! I will accept you answer as soon as I am allowed to ;)